# Could not find asset web_components|lib/webcomponents.js

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I am using Dart Editor version 1.8.0.release (STABLE) with Dart SDK version 1.8.0.

When I do a build dart2js I get the error:
"/Volumes/data/b/build/slave/dart-editor-mac-stable/build/dart/sdk/lib/_internal/pub_generated/lib/src/barback/pub_package_provider.dart 87  PubPackageProvider._assertExists
/Volumes/data/b/build/slave/dart-editor-mac-stable/build/dart/sdk/lib/_internal/pub_generated/lib/src/barback/pub_package_provider.dart 41  getAsset..join0.join1
/Volumes/data/b/build/slave/dart-editor-mac-stable/build/dart/sdk/lib/_internal/pub_generated/lib/src/barback/pub_package_provider.dart 52  getAsset..join0
/Volumes/data/b/build/slave/dart-editor-mac-stable/build/dart/sdk/lib/_internal/pub_generated/lib/src/barback/pub_package_provider.dart 76  getAsset.
dart:isolate                                                                                                                                _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage
This is an unexpected error. Please run

```
pub --trace 'build' '--mode' 'debug' '--all'
```

and include the results in a bug report on http://dartbug.com/new."

Nothing is built into /build. It was working with SDK version 1.7. Anyone have some helpful feedback?

thanks!

Comment: See also http://dartbug.com/21810

Comment: Can you please add your `pubspec.yaml`, `index.html`, `index.dart` if any and the Polymer versions your are using.

Comment: Having the same problem as that dart bug. Easiest way to mitigate is to add a version constraint to pubspec.yaml like so: polymer: '>=0.15.0 <0.15.2' Apparently the new version of polymer is not fully baked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Delete the .pub folder in the root of your project, then run pub get.

I just tried doing this step and it worked for me.

Credit to Günter for finding this: https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=21810#c9